# GSAP + AdHelper Template results in 'lib is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, gsap

When using the [GSAP Templates for Animate CC 2017](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16040-gsap-templates-for-animate-cc-2017/), I get an error in Chrome's Console tab when publishing and testing the creatives in **Animate CC 2017.5**:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: lib is not defined
at e.t.timeSync (GSAP_AdStarter_2017.html?20878:169)
at handleComplete (GSAP_AdStarter_2017.html?20878:131)
at init (GSAP_AdStarter_2017.html?20878:63)
at onload (GSAP_AdStarter_2017.html?20878:155)
```

This is when trying to publish the *GSAP_AdStarter_2017.fla* file with no changes; simply open the file and use Control > Test (Ctrl/CMD+Enter).

Some things I've tried to remedy the problem:

- Speaking to our in-house JS devs, but they were unable to help with the problem. Unfortunately, they are not well versed with Animate CC.
- Using other versions of Animate CC, up to and including Animate CC 2019.
- Testing the file on a different (PC) computer. The result was the same.
- Opening the published HTML file in Firefox. The result was the same.

It should also be noted that the HTML5 creative opens fine before trying to publish it myself.

My overall objective with using this template is to try to find a solution to an issue effecting our HTML5 creatives. The issue is that all HTML5 creatives are running at approximately 50% the intended framerate on iDevices and Safari (desktop), until the user interacts with the creative (ie. tapping it). I believe using the Timesync function from gskinner's AdHelper library will fix this issue, but I can't tell for sure until I'm able to get a properly working creative!

I'm quite surprised the above issue I describe isn't more frequently asked and even more surprised that I can't find any solid topics on why Apple seem to be throttling HTML5 Canvas content on iDevices. Surely this has caused pain for a lot of HTML5 creative designers and animators, especially those not very technically skilled.

Any help is hugely appreciated and I'll post any additional information if requested.

Here's a [direct download link](https://greensock.com/forums/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=2347) to the templates I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

In future updates of Animate CC (since 2017) they created the `lib` variable inside the `init()` function, making this variable not available for the adhelper code that is at the bottom of the document.

The solution is to move the `lib` variable to just after the open script tag, *outside* of the `init()` function.

If you use the adhelper template file, move the command `$CREATE_LOADER` to the mentioned place after the opening script tag. Then everything should work fine again.

One note, don't use GSAP 3. Adhelper is written for GSAP 2 or lower.